# How can Windows boot with Bitlocker after clearing the TPM?

Tags: windows-10, boot, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

After installing Windows, I turned on Bitlocker for a full C:\ drive encryption. I saved the recovery keys and then let Bitlocker proceed with encrypting the full drive.

When I rebooted, I was surprised that the system booted completely fine without prompting for a pin. I guess Bitlocker is asking the TPM (AMD fTPM) for keys to decrypt the drive, tell me if I'm wrong.

So I tried to make the TPM require a pin before giving away all his little secrets. I found how to change the "Local Computer Policy" and configured the "Require additional authentication at startup" settings, requiring a pin.

I then proceeded to set a pin for my C:\ drive, which went perfectly fine. I rebooted and was prompted for a pin, which I thought was the end of the story.

But I wanted to test clearing the TPM to be sure that it was the component storing the keys (I have the Bitlocker recovery key, so that shouldn't be a problem). I cleared the TPM using the windows TPM GUI.

To my big surprise, when I rebooted Windows, I wasn't prompted for a pin, NOR A RECOVERY KEY! The system booted perfectly fine, but Bitlocker was in a suspended state! How is this possible after clearing the TPM? The keys should be gone forever! Have them been copied to a readable zone on my disk?

Am I misunderstanding how Bitlocker and the TPM work together?

Comment: Sounds like BitLocker is currently suspended.  Can you verify if that is the case?

Comment: It is, what does it mean? It entered a suspended state when I cleared the TPM to avoid being locked out?

Comment: ["Suspension of BitLocker does not mean that BitLocker decrypts data on the volume. Instead, suspension makes key used to decrypt the data available to everyone in the clear. New data written to the disk is still encrypted"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/suspend-bitlocker?view=win10-ps). You might look over [manage-bde: protectors](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde-protectors) and read about and test with the `-tpmandpinandstartupkey` parameter.

Comment: Ok, so now I guess the keys have been written to a non-encrypted disk partition. What a nice feature for someone wanting to read all the data! This is dumb

Comment: @mimipc - Please provide the necessary information so I can answer your question.  The keys have NOT been written to a non-encrypted disk partition.  Can you please, just verify, if BitLocker is suspended or not?

Comment: @Ramhound, a I said, it was in a suspended state when I rebooted. I rebooted again and the pin is back and the TPM is back to normal. The only thing I'm worried about is that it wrote the keys to a non-encrypted zone for suspended mode and that someone could recover them.

Comment: @mimipc - When you resumed BitLocker, the data you were worried about was deleted, since it was written to an encrypted data you have nothing to worry about.  However, as currently written your question does not contain the fact BitLocker was in a suspended state, so this question cannot be answered in its current state.  Suspending BitLocker is how you would update the TPM firmware, so the fact BitLocker was suspended does not increase/decrease your security situation.  It is a necssary state in some maintenance actions.

Comment: @Ramhound - Windows should state that clearing the TPM will put Bitlocker in a suspended state. I didn't want that, and now I can't be sure the temporary keys have been properly shreded. Clearing the TPM should lock you out and prompt for the recovery key, that's it.

Comment: So for "*How can Windows boot with Bitlocker after clearing the TPM?*", it sounds like you need to ensure you really clear the tpm and ensure it's not in suspended state before you reboot. If the tpm is clear and the BitLocker is not suspended, then it should prompt for recovery I would think. Look over [Clear-Tpm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/trustedplatformmodule/clear-tpm?view=win10-ps) for a method to clear the TPM.

Comment: @mimipc - It normally does.  I suspect the reason it did not was due to the fact you required a pin.  At that point, the TPM key wasn't specifically required, since you were providing the pin.  However, because there was a modification to the configuration, BitLocker was suspended to avoid being unable to boot into your system at all.

Answer (score 1):

Self-answering my question thanks to Ramhound's help.

When clearing the TPM, Windows automatically switches to Bitlocker's suspended mode. This mode keeps the volume key on a non-encrypted sector of the drive. When the system reboots, it uses the clear key to read the volume and takes back the ownership of the TPM, which disables suspended mode.

The following links give information on how the clear key is stored and how forensics could help reading the volume if it has been placed in suspended mode :

- https://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/8qvwvv/when_suspending_bitlocker_protection_where_is_the/
- http://jessekornblum.com/publications/di09.pdf

Comment: This is indeed correct. If you had cleared the TPM from the firmware, you would've been challenged for the recovery key. Windows is just making things convenient for you by suspending protection first, then re-enabling it after a reboot, when it can re-save the keys back to the TPM.